# Java android multidimensional array (hash maybe) with string and nested class

Tags: java, android, hash, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to track class stats for an android game I'm working on.

```
public static class characterClasses {
    public String class_name;
    public int base_hp;
    public int base_attack;
    public float base_defense;
    }
```

I want to access these directly by name so I won't have to iterate over them repeatedly. From my research it looks like a hashmap or map would be what I need but everything I've seen is only for a single key/value pair. I need to access each stat value directly by class and value, something like

classList.get("warrior").get("base_hp");

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to think of using  `HashMap`. You can use the `characterClass String names` as `keys` and the `characterClasses` as values. You can then use your `getter` methods to access your specific fields i.e.

```
classList.get("warrior").getBase_HP();
```

You could also forget maps entirely since these stats seem constant by using inheritance

```
public class Character {
  int hp;
  int attack;
  int defense;

  public Character (int hp, int attack, int defense) {
    this.hp = hp;
    this.attack = attack;
    this.defense = defense;
  }

  public int getHP() {
    return hp;
  }

  ...
}
```

For your Character subclasses, you can preset those values in the constructor

```
public class Warrior extends Character {

  public Warrior() {
    super(2, 10, 8);
  }

  public int getHP() {
    return super.getHP();
  }
}

public class Wizard extends Character {

  public Wizard() {
    super(10, 3, 1);
  }

  public int getHP() {
    return super.getHP();
  }
}
```

This way all your Warrior and Wizard Objects will have the same stats that can be accessed any time simply by invoking their getters.

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks! I'm loading the initial values from a database with a row for each class stats. Since I can't create dynamic variable for the class name how can I reference the class I need to set or get? I may just be thinking about this the wrong way but I can't seem to wrap my thought process on how to get from the variable cc.class_name to get/set the Warrior/Wizard class. At least not without checking if the cc.class_name == "warrior" etc. which seems like a waste.

Comment: @Sym If you use the inheritance solution, then you will know which type of object you have because of the class instance.

Comment: So as you loop through your database, check the name row. For example if `name = "wizard"` Wizard wiz = new Wizard(); characters.add(wiz); You can use a `switch` statement to evaluate the name and create different objects for your different objects.

Comment: I see. So there isn't a way to access it based on the value of the data from the database? There will be a lot of classes. That's why I was looking at the maps to start with. I can't do Character cc.class_name = new Character();

Comment: After a bit more research, the info you posted, and a bit of trial and error I have something that will work like I want. Thanks!